# Azure Prod and Dev Role Configuration

Tags: .net, testing, deployment, azure, roles

We're moving our site to Azure and want to make sure we do things the right way.

We have our development region where we test before deploying to production - not sure the right way to set this up in Azure.

I was thinking we'd want to have one solution with two roles which point to our test and prod Azure instances. This way we can publish to dev, complete testing and then publish right to prod.

Is this possible / the right way? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of this depends on which service you are using, Web Sites, Virtual Machines, or Cloud Services. I'm going to assume we're talking cloud services.

Set up two cloud services. This gives you two fixed dns names that you can then easily map your own custom domains too. Next up, create you copies of the cscfg file (cloud service configuration file), one for your production environment, one for your pre-prod environment. When you do your deployment, hand the correct file for the environment you are deploying too.

All your environment specific confirmation settings (connection strings for example), will do in the cscfg files.

Comment: This makes sense to me, wasn't sure if two Roles were needed.

Comment: Its not two roles, its two cloud services (in windows azure). This gives you two fixed DNS namespaces that you can use. When you deploy to service namespace A, you use cscfg A, when you deploy to service namespace B, you use cscfg B.

Answer (score 0):

Actually having two roles for this purpose is a bad idea - you want your test environment be as similar to production as possible. A better alternative is to have two different service configurations (.cscfg) files that will store connection strings and other stuff that isolates production service data from test service data.

Comment: I'm not talking role, I'm talking two services.

Comment: @BrentDaCodeMonkey: Yes, this will take two services, but the OP initially wanted "one solution with two roles".